# Party optimization: maximum weight independent set in a tree/graph

Tags: graphs

From [Cornell](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2011sp/lectures/lec22-memoization/memo.htm)

> Suppose we want to throw a party for a company whose organization
>   chart is a binary tree. Each employee has an associated fun value, and
>   we want the set of invited employees to have the maximum total fun,
>   which is the sum of the fun values of the invited employees. However,
>   no one has fun if some employee and that employee's direct superior
>   are both invited, so we never invite two employees who are directly
>   connected in the organization chart. (The less whimsical name for this
>   problem is the maximum weight independent set in a tree.)

I was trying to think of an analogous statement if the problem were a graph rather than a tree. Might we say that now we want to throw the largest possible party with ex-girlfriends/ex-boyfriends such that no one's ex-partner is invited?

In this case an edge between two members denotes a ex-relationship. We want to find the largest set such that no two members share an edge.

Is this a correct interpretation of the graph problem and is there a known polynomial time algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can interpret a graph problem in whatever way you wish. Note that your interpretation makes sense only for bipartite graphs.

Maximum independent set, even with all weights the same, is (almost) NP-hard to approximate within a factor of $n^{1-\epsilon}$ for any fixed $\epsilon > 0$ (here $n$ is the number of vertices); the actual hardness assumption is NP$\not\subseteq$BPP rather than P$\neq$NP (see for example Anupam Gupta's [lecture notes](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~anupamg/adv-approx/lecture25.pdf)). Under the exponential time hypothesis, any $r$-approximation algorithm must run in at least $2^{n^{1-\epsilon}/r^{1+\epsilon}}$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ (see [Chalermsook, Laekhanukit and Nanongkai](http://people.idsia.ch/~laekhanukit/paper/pricing.pdf)).

Comment: Can you please explain why my interpretation only makes sense for bipartite graphs?

Comment: @rookie An edge connects a man and a woman. Unless you had a more modern interpretation in mind.