# Tracing a polynomial algorithm for the problem of maximum-weight independent set

Tags: algorithms, graphs

It should be a very easy question, but I am a little bit confused.
According to [party optimization](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/47251/party-optimization-maximum-weight-independent-set-in-a-tree-graph) post, the Maximum-weight Independent Set for trees can be found in the poly-nominal time using Dynamic Programming (the Algorithm is also explained on page 562 of the book [Algorithm Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321295358)). Now, imagine that we want to trace the algorithm on a random graph like the figure below where the numbers in the balls show the weight.
[image]

I want to know, does it matter which node I am selecting as the root?
Can you please guide me through the steps of this algorithm's tracing on this graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't matter which node you select as the root, in the sense that the algorithm will always find a maximum-weight independent set. The actual set of nodes selected by the algorithm might differ, if there are multiple maximum-weight solutions.

Let's say the root is the node with weight 2. Either it is in the optimal solution, or it isn't.

- If it is, then 7, 10, and 7 are not; the remaining tree only contains 4. Thus this solution has weight 2 + 4 = 6.
- If it is not, then the answer is the maximum-weight independent set on the forest in which the components are the subtrees with weight 7, 10, and (7, 4). Solving the problem recursively on the subtrees gives 7 + 10 + 7 = 24.

Since 24 > 6, the answer is 24.

Comment: Thank you so much for your very clear explanation.